# How do I change the settings of the sounds in iOS 6?

Tags: ios

As you see. I have accidentally pressed something that change my iOS sound. When I try to volume up or down my sounds. It says sound effects. If I watch a video. It does not say anything. Is it in the iOS or did press anything? If I did, please help me.

Comment: Have you tried tapping the screen once while a video is playing, and dragging the volume slider (at the bottom) all the way to the right, so that it's all blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to Settings > Sounds and setting 'Change with Buttons' to Off.